# How to average a value in a time window for multiple days, in Mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql, average

Having this simple log table

```
id  |val   |dt
-------------------------
 A  100     2014-01-15 00:00:00     
 A  160     2014-01-15 00:00:00      
 A  100     2014-01-15 01:00:00     
 A  160     2014-01-15 02:00:00
 A  200     2014-01-15 03:00:00
 A  80      2014-01-16 01:00:00
 B  100     2014-01-16 02:00:00
 B  200     2014-01-16 01:00:00
 B  100     2014-01-15 02:00:00
 and so on...
```

I can average a SINGLE day(15), of a SINGLE given id (A), in a specified range (0-2) by doing this

```
select id, 
       date(dt),
       AVG(val) as av
from (SELECT id, val, dt
      FROM test
      WHERE id = 'A' AND 
            (date(dt) BETWEEN '2014-01-15' AND '2014-01-15') AND 
            ( (time(dt) BETWEEN '00:00' AND '02:00'))) as outerTable
```

I get this SINGLE result

```
id  |date   | average 00:00 to 2:00
-------------------------
A   2014-01-15  120.0000
```

But how to solve that average of MULTIPLE days in same time period, but in many days in range of months? years? like

```
id  |date   | average 00:00 to 2:00
-------------------------
A   2014-01-15  120.0000
A   2014-01-16  80.0000 
A   2014-01-17  35.0000
and so on...
```

Need of loop the same query on different days for the whole month or year, of course the literal loop can be done in php, but it is SLOW, Also I could loop for every ID, making it slower.

Comment: Your query isn't even valid ANSI SQL you normally can't mix non-aggregated columns with a aggregated column without `GROUP BY`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to use Subquery, to get the data and then calculate the average in the Outer query. It can be done without the subquery itself.

In order to get the average value for different dates, you can remove the `WHERE` condition on date, to get the data for all the date(s). You can also change the `WHERE` condition on date to include a range instead.

You also seem to want results for different `id` values. We can get rid of `WHERE` condition on `id` as well.

Eventually, you can do a `GROUP BY` on the `id` and `date`, to get individual rows idwise, and then datewise.

```
SELECT 
  id, 
  DATE(dt)
  AVG(val) 
FROM test
WHERE 
  TIME(dt) BETWEEN '00:00' AND '02:00'
GROUP BY id, DATE(dt)
```

Comment: Don't forget the date range condition `date(dt) BETWEEN '2014-01-15' AND '2014-01-15' ` the topicstarter had in this own query.

Comment: @RaymondNijland OP wants the data for all the date(s).

Comment: "OP wants the data for all the date(s)" You sure? check "But how to solve that average of MULTIPLE days in same time period, but in many days in range of months? years? like" in this question... His question seams a bit contradictory on that point..

Comment: @RaymondNijland his words are conflicting with the sample data and expected output. I will wait for OP to clarify further. It should be a trivial correction in any case.

Comment: thanks, this answers seems solve a part of the problem, it indeed avoid looping "day by day", but as @RaymondNijland say, it still don't let specify a day range, also it still has to loop for id's

Comment: @HernánEche you can remove `WHERE` condition on `id` to avoid looping for id(s).

Comment: Great, I'll try also adding date range in the where condition.

Comment: @HernánEche and yes, I have mentioned in the explanation also; that you can easily add date range in where condition, to account for a bigger range of date.

Comment: Slow like a snail but faster than loops! +1

Comment: @HernánEche do you have any indexing defined on the tables ?